# UIButton fails to play sound

Tags: unity, c#, audio

I'm doing this game where with cards you assign different beats to different channels. You drag and drop the beat to a channel and it gets added to the mixer. What I'm having trouble with is when i try to play each channel individually with an UI Button. This is the script attached to the channels:

```
public class ManageChannel : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource thisAudioSource;
    bool chequeo;
    string Nombre;

    public AudioMixer audioMixer;
 



    public void AsignaCanal (){
        Nombre = this.name; // tomo el nombre del canal actual 
        thisAudioSource = this.GetComponent<AudioSource>();

        var carta = this.transform.GetChild(0); // llamo a la carta hija de este objeto
        thisAudioSource.clip = carta.GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip;
        thisAudioSource.outputAudioMixerGroup = audioMixer.FindMatchingGroups(Nombre)[0]; // asigno al AudioSource el grupo correspondiente
        
    } 
    
    public void comienzaAudio (){
        if (!thisAudioSource.isPlaying){
            thisAudioSource.Play();
        }
        else {
            thisAudioSource.Stop();
        }
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        chequeo = true;
       
       
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (this.transform.childCount != 0 && chequeo) {
                AsignaCanal();
                chequeo = false;
                thisAudioSource.Play();
        
        } 
    

    }
}
```

What the script does is when a card is dropped, it takes the clip of the card and get its into the `AudioSource` of the channel, and that `AudioSource` gets outputted to its respective channel (for example, the `GameObject` "Channel 1" goes to the mixer group "Channel 1" and so on). Then i've tried to build the buttons to reproduce the track of each channel individually, but using `AudioSource.Play()` since I believe I cannot do it with the AudioMixer directly. What i did is create a UIButton and then assign the respective `GameObject` Channel to the `OnClick()` section on the inspector, and then i choose the following function on the script that i showed before

```
public void comienzaAudio (){
        if (!thisAudioSource.isPlaying){
            thisAudioSource.Play();
        }
        else {
            thisAudioSource.Stop();
        }
    }
```

Then, every time i press the button, that function should be called. The problem is nothing happens. I'm positive the button is working because i tested with a `bool` value and a `Debug.Log()` to see if it changes values with every click, and it does. So, i honestly have no clue what the issue is. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not spotting any immediate issue with your code. Here are some easy things to try:

- Make sure your mixer is not muted or set at too low of a volume (try playing audio through the mixer using some other approach, e.g. "play on awake").
- Make sure the AudioSource volume is not set too low, and that the spread/spatial settings are correct
- Add logging code to ensure everything is set up correctly (this should usually be your first step in debugging):

```
public void comienzaAudio (){
        
    print("Clip: " + thisAudioSource.clip);
    print("Mixer: " + thisAudioSource.outputAudioMixerGroup);
    print("isPlaying: " + thisAudioSource.isPlaying);
    print("Volume: " + thisAudioSource.volume);
    print("Max distance: " + thisAudioSource.maxDistance);

    if (!thisAudioSource.isPlaying){
        thisAudioSource.Play();
    } else {
        thisAudioSource.Stop();
    }
}
```